# How to avoid numerous If statements?

Tags: python-2.7, argparse

**Description:**

I'm using a small script in order to execute another script, which belongs to a set of scripts, depending on which option is given. For example: If option --PatchPanel is given, only CreatePatchPanel.py will be executed, even if option --Room is given as well. The order of the IF statements reflects the priority of scripts.

**My code:**

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--Room', action='store', dest='room', help='')
parser.add_argument('--Enclosure', action='store', dest='enclosure', help='')
parser.add_argument('--PatchPanel', nargs='*',  action='store',
dest='patchpanel', help='')
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.patchpanel:
    execfile('CreatePatchPanel.py')

elif args.enclosure:
    execfile('CreateEnclosure.py')

elif args.room:
    execfile('CreateRoom.py')
```

With 3 options 7 cases are possible. Each option individually, together in combination of 2 options, and all options together. I want my script to execute the sub-scripts accordingly. Assuming that the options --PatchPanel and --Room be given, I want CreatePatchPanel.py being executed first and CreateRoom.py being executed afterwards.

**My approach so far:**

I try to cover every case by an if statement:

```
...
if args.patchpanel and args.enclosure:
    execfile('CreatePatchPanel.py')
    execfile('CreateEnclosure.py')

if args.patchpanel and args.room:
    execfile('CreatePatchPanel.py')
    execfile('CreateRoom.py')

if args.enclosure and args.room:
    ... 
    ...   
...
```

But this will lead to a lot of if statements in the case of a lot more of options.

**My Question:**

Is there a programming technique or a paradigm that allows me to get around the formulation of numerous IF statements? Is there perhaps an obvious solution to my problem, which I have overlooked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use 3 regular if-statements in your first example, instead of else-if. Wouldn't that do the trick?

Comment: Oops. I was too quick. Didn't take your special cases into account.